# Unable to run jest tests in React typescript. Jest encountered an unexpected token

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have picked up an old project, and I'm trying to run jest-tests on it.

But I'm incapable of doing so. The error is the following:

```
portal: session.TP_P ?? "",
                        ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token ?

  1 | import React from "react";
  2 | import { InputEmail, InputCommon, Button, SCFormSimple, SCForm, SCFormSimpleTitle, SCFormSimpleButtons, Column, TipoEnvio, CheckBoxCmps, getUrl, Modal } from "own-core-components";
> 3 | import { solicitante, emailSolicitante } from '../../helpers/session';
    | ^
  4 | 
  5 | export interface IProps {
  6 |   onHandleSubmit: Function;

  at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/script_transformer.js:403:17)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/components/from/FormTrafico.tsx:3:1)
```

And the test case is as follows

```
import React from "react";
import {
  mount,
  shallow
} from "enzyme";
import FormTrafico from "../../components/from/FormTrafico"

describe('<FormTrafico />', () => {
  it("renders a Modal when modalCondTraf is true", () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(< FormTrafico />);
    wrapper.setProps({
      modalCondTraf: true
    })
    expect(wrapper.find(FormTrafico).exists()).toBe(true);
  })
})
```

The code of the file to test is quite long but its a common react class based component

```
import React from "react";
import { InputEmail, InputCommon, Button, SCFormSimple, SCForm, SCFormSimpleTitle, SCFormSimpleButtons, Column, TipoEnvio, CheckBoxCmps, getUrl, Modal } from "own-core-components";
import { solicitante, emailSolicitante } from '../../helpers/session';

export interface IProps {
  onHandleSubmit: Function;
  onChangeTipoEnvio?: Function
  codproductoUrgente?: any
  codproductoNormal?: any
  gestoriaData?: any;
  modalChange: Function;
};

export interface IState {
  paramsRequeridos?: any;
  paramsData?: any;
  modalCondTraf: boolean;
};

export default class FormTrafico extends React.PureComponent<IProps, IState> {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      paramsData: [],
      modalCondTraf: false,
      paramsRequeridos: {
        matricula: {
          forceValidacion: false
        },
        solicitante: {
          forceValidacion: false
        },
        email: {
          forceValidacion: false
        },
        politica: {
          forceValidacion: false
        }

      }
    }
  }


  componentDidMount() {
    this.handleDataForSubmit("isNormal", 0, false)
  }
  ///.......more code
```

My setupTets.js looks as follows. I had to add the `matchMedia` block for it to not give `matchMedia` errors

```
import Enzyme from "enzyme";
import Adapter from "enzyme-adapter-react-16";
Enzyme.configure({
  adapter: new Adapter()
});

window.requestAnimationFrame =
  window.requestAnimationFrame ||
  function (callback) {
    setTimeout(callback, 0);
  };

window.scrollTo = () => "";

window.matchMedia = window.matchMedia || function () {
  return {
    matches: false,
    addListener: function () {},
    removeListener: function () {}
  };
};
```

And my run test script looks as follows

```
 "test": "cross-env SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true react-scripts test --verbose false --transformIgnorePatterns \"node_modules/(?!(own-core-components))/\" --transformIgnorePatterns \"node_modules/(?!(ei-core-helpers))/\" ",
```

I'm using the following versions

```
"enzyme": "^3.10.0",
"enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.15.1",
```

This is the whole error msg

Jest encountered an unexpected token

> ```
> This usually means that you are trying to import a file which Jest cannot parse, e.g. it's not plain JavaScript.
>
> By default, if Jest sees a Babel config, it will use that to transform your files, ignoring "node_modules".
>
> Here's what you can do:
>  • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
>  • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
>  • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config
> ```
>
> option.

Comment: what is in the file `../../helpers/session`

Comment: @Khai it has a couple functions that fetch the local storage and set some values. Apparently it has a function ````basicSess```` with the following content  ```portal: session.TP_P ?? "",```

Comment: @Khai Ive changed ?? to || and seems to work, I dont know what ?? means

Comment: I was just going to ask if your code was capable of handling [nullish coalescing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) and to try `||` instead. `??` is the nullish coalescing operator.

Comment: well using || instead of ?? seems to solve it

Comment: Solved by updating node to the latest version

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved by updating node to the latest version